# Compare columns from two dataframe and cbind the rows from df2 to df1 when matching

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to find a way to compare two data frame, the logic for comparing part below, example for first dataframe (df1)

```
order   billing_doc  gst_invoice_no
2321    938456847    GT8476534
7465    943758465    HG3485634
3475    253426365    GT3475634
2534    215431233    HY8347534
```

Example of second document (df2)

```
order_number    shipment_number   invoice_number    final_status
3347            28I4Y348843       GT36543265        Delivered
2376            WEKRUH32343       234U652763        Dispatched
2732            93745874654       HT35426343        Invoiced
5434            34598749R43       HY32562343        Delivered
2344            WUTR7635632       HU35642653        Packed
2331            2343234IUY4       FER3542542        Cancelled
```

The logic to compare these two data frame is:

1. Compare gst_invoice_no column from df1 to invoice_number from df2, if there is a match cbind the row from df2 to df1;
2. If there is no match then compare the same column gst_invoice_no from df1 to shipment_number from df2 if there is a match cbind the row from df2 to df1.

I believe my previous question was a bit overwhelming.  Please suggest a way to achieve the first two steps.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the `df2` in long format keeping `invoice_number` and `shipment_number` in the same column and then do a join.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
              tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(invoice_number, shipment_number), 
                           values_to = 'gst_invoice_no'), by = 'gst_invoice_no')
```

---

For larger datasets we can use `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
setDT(df1)

df3 <- df1[melt(df2, measure.vars = c('shipment_number', 'invoice_number'), 
     value.name = "gst_invoice_no"), on = 'gst_invoice_no']

df3[, .SD[1L], gst_invoice_no]
```

Comment: Hi, im getting this error : "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 553.6 Mb
In addition: Warning message:
Column `gst_invoice_no` joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector "

Comment: Thank you it worked. But the problem is i have multiple values of df1 in df2, which creates duplicates in df1, is there a way we can get the first match we find and then cbind that row from df2 to df1 ?

Comment: We can select 1st row for each `gst_invoice_no `. Check if the update helps.